# Mule IBM MQ JMS transport acknowledgements

Tags: mule

We have a requirement that is looking to send an acknowledgement message once it puts message on output queue (indicating that it has put the message), I see that if we set the mule reply to property than the acknowledgement does get sends but we need to consume the output queue for it (consumption is possible only from downstream system), so can i please ask how we can send the acknowledgement to the ack queue for the purpose that message was put on the output queue without the need for consumption from it. I am using JMS transport and mule 3.4.2